# How to use AJAX Control Toolkit client-side functionality without IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I ran an ASP.NET page that i have under development on my local IIS. It uses some dragPanelExtenders as well as some other AJAX Control Toolkit AJAX client side stuff, and in order to show the page to somebody, I wanted to put it up as a plain HTML file, hosted on a live web server (running APACHE). (This is the only public web server I have access to, and I want them to be able to drag some panels and experience the page as it would be when "live")

So, I viewed the page running on my local IIS, then saved the source as a HTML file.

Then copied this HTML file to the web server ( as well as necessary CSS, JS and image files).

When I view this HTML file through the web server, I get this error :

ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.

By debugging, I see that the following lines were in my saved HTML :

**<script src="/Insata10/WebResource.axd**?d=VAXZudqFsChpNfB" type="text/javascript">

**<script src="/Insata10/ScriptResource.axd**?d=Dwbyv-OIp-kJQdqf_UMh7wUzi2" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
**if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');**

So, at runtime, the referenced resources "ScriptResource.axd" and "WebResource.axd" were not found.

Is there any way to get whatever is needed from those AXD's to my HTML file, without actually executing anything on IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.  The Ajax Control Toolkit relies on server-side .NET Code, which runs in the context of IIS.

You can us a different web server, such as the Cassini web server that comes with Visual Studio (or write your own), but I expect that you're looking for a simpler solution, and none exist for what you're asking.

The bottom line is, the server-side code needs to run, and for that you need a server.  You can't just open the file and have it work.

The best you could do would be to find similar javascript to get the desired funcitonality.

*edit*

I'm always forgetting about Mono, so if your Apache server is set up and configured correctly, you CAN run .NET code from an Apache server.  http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Still not simple, though, so my answer of "not easily" does not change.